# ProgMP page showing I'm not using MPTCP even when I'm using it

Tags: tcp, network-programming, scheduling, mptcp

I'm started exploring MPTCP recently and started using it on my Ubuntu 18.04. My MPTCP version is 0.95. `curl http://multipath-tcp.org` on my terminal is returning `Yay, you are MPTCP-capable! You can now rest in peace.` I further checked it on `http://amiusingmptcp.de/` which is telling me I'm using MPTCP. Now I want to write my own default scheduler. So I clicked on appropriate link on `http://amiusingmptcp.de/` page which took me to `http://progmp.net/progmp.html` page. In this page it is showing that I'm not using MPTCP connection so the demo page is showing limited features. I have attached the relevant screenshots. Can someone please tell me how to make my own scheduler?
Thanks[image: ProgMP page][image: am_i_using_MPTCP]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must be on multiple interface to do so. Also, for the local machine based setup without 
internet (local network only) you can install the progmp kernel onto your own machine.

In order to do so in your terminal,

```
wget -c http://progmp.net/tools/linux-image-4.1.20-ProgMp.deb
# then 
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-4.1.20-ProgMp.deb
to install the kernel
```

After that boot into grub menu and select the progMP kernel. the `uname -a` should prompt kernel version 4.1.20.
Now for writing your own scheduler you can download the example code from progmp.net site and use the python script to add it to the system.
here is the further documentation in order to proceed, along with detailed steps:
http://progmp.net/